# Fan-Gate using FB SDK 4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to connect an app to a facebook page ... up till that it's fine as it displays in the tabs. Also a simple echo works fine.

I'm using this guide to get it working: https://www.webniraj.com/2014/06/11/facebook-api-creating-page-apps-using-facebook-php-sdk-4-0-x/

I have tried to set some echos so I'd know where it's getting stuck and from what I have it seems it's getting stuck in the

```
$pageHelper = new FacebookPageTabHelper();
```

The code works fine on the server where it is uploaded

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks :)

Comment: If the same code works on the server, then it's likely a config issue with your localhost. Verify that the App ID and Secret are current (if they differ from the server version), and make sure the Tag URL is setup correctly.

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial is aweful. All those require calls when you could just use the existing autoloader.php instead. FacebookPageTabHelper extends FacebookCanvasLoginHelper, so you don´t have to add it separately.

Try this one instead: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-tutorial/

See "Using the Page Tab Helper" in the article:

```
require 'phpsdk4/autoload.php';

use Facebook\Helpers\FacebookPageTabHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APP-ID', 'APP-SECRET');

$helper = new FacebookPageTabHelper();

echo '<p>page id: ' . $helper->getPageId() . '</p>';
echo '<p>liked: ' . $helper->isLiked() . '</p>';
echo '<p>admin: ' . $helper->isAdmin() . '</p>';
```

**Important: You need PHP 5.4+ to use the new PHP SDK.** - If the code does not work, it´s most likely a problem with the server.

Comment: Hi first of all thank you for your recommendation :), second, the code still does not work... I am using heroku as a hosting and it uses PHP 5.5, in fact it works when I just go to the link where the app is, but not on facebook...

Comment: Further debugging led me to believe that the problem is in the SignedRequest.php where there is     

     $this->payload = SignedRequest::parse($rawSignedRequest, $state, $appSecret);

Comment: i actually tested that code, works perfectly fine for me. maybe there is some problem with your app settings? are you really trying on a page tab? what means "it does not work"?

Comment: FacebookPageTabHelper does require FacebookCanvasLoginHelper. If you see the code, `class FacebookPageTabHelper extends FacebookCanvasLoginHelper`. The only difference is that the autoload.php file automatically adds them to the code.

Comment: what i mean is that you do not have to "use" it, as it extends it anyway. i will clarify it in the answer.

Comment: I don't know .. I'm using heroku to upload the apps... the code is getting stuck at static::parse and I'm not sure why in SignedRequest.php